# I have some JSON but I want to extract data based on a variable using jq

Tags: json, parsing, environment-variables, jq

I have some JSON data which I want to parse using jq

```
{{
    "metadata":{
      "name":"run1",
      "uid":"b2c0ce",
      "creationTimestamp":"2021-01-01T01:01:01Z"
    },
    "spec":{
      "arguments":{}
    },
    "status":{
      "phase":"Failed",
      "startedAt":"2021-01-01T01:01:01Z",
      "finishedAt":"2021-01-01T01:01:01Z"
    }
},
{
    "metadata":{
      "name":"run2",
      "uid":"9b0af3",
      "creationTimestamp":"2021-01-01T01:01:01Z"
    },
    "spec":{
      "arguments":{}
    },
    "status":{
      "phase":"Succeeded",
      "startedAt":"2021-01-01T01:01:01Z",
      "finishedAt":"2021-01-01T01:01:01Z"}}}
```

I have a script that a user will enter a "name" and I want to be able to look for and extract the metadata for the name they entered if it exists. So for example if they enter "run7" I wanted the final output to be:

```
{"metadata":{
    "name":"run7",
    "uid":"b2c0ce",
    "creationTimestamp":"2021-01-01T01:01:01Z"}
```

or if possible to just show

```
"name":"run7",
"uid":"b2c0ce",
"creationTimestamp":"2021-01-01T01:01:01Z"
```

The closest ive gotten is:

```
jq -r '.[] | .[] | map({name: .name, uid: .uid, time: .creationTimestamp })'  file.json
```

but im not sure how I can now search only for a certain name. The way I did it gives this:

```
{
    "name": "run10",
    "uid": "af7b51f",
    "time": "2021-01-01T01:01:01Z"
  },
  {
    "name": null,
    "uid": null,
    "time": null
  },
  {
    "name": null,
    "uid": null,
    "time": null
  }
```

I also dont want it to check the "spec" or "status" because thats where the null came from

Comment: Please fix your input json. It's not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming those input objects are in an array,

```
.[] | select(.metadata.name == "run2") | .metadata
```

Will select the object where `.metadata.name === run2`.

Then it shows the `.metadata` of that object so the output becomes:

```json
{
  "name": "run2",
  "uid": "9b0af3",
  "creationTimestamp": "2021-01-01T01:01:01Z"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zPyScdoGNx)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. The second part didnt work `| .metadata` but I just included `jq -r .uid` instead which is what I wanted the whole time